# Search through a big collection of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, search

i have a really big collection of objects that i want to search through.

**The array have > 60.000 items** and the search performance can be really slow from time to time.

One object in that array looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "title"
  "company": "abc company"
  "rating": 13 // internal rating based on comments and interaction
  ...
}
```

I want to search for the title and the company info and order that by the rating of the items.

This is what my search currently look like:

```
    onSearchInput(searchTerm) {
        (<any>window).clearTimeout(this.searchInputTimeout);
        this.searchInputTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchForFood(searchTerm);
        }, 500);
    }

    searchForFood(searchTerm) {
        if (searchTerm.length > 1) {
            this.searchResults = [];
            this.foodList.map(item => {
                searchTerm.split(' ').map(searchTermPart => {
                    if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTermPart.toLowerCase())
                        || item.company.toLowerCase().includes(searchTermPart.toLowerCase())) {
                        this.searchResults.push(item);
                    }
                });
            });

            this.searchResults = this.searchResults.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.rating - b.rating;
            }).reverse();

        } else {
            this.searchResults = [];
        }
    }
```

**Question:** Is there any way to improve the search logic and performance wise?

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `that` in that first function.

Comment: well, thats true. Already changed :)

Comment: Tell us more about the search - is it exact match, starts-with, partial match? This impacts the answer; although the answer is going to be a classic Big-O pattern of some kind.

Comment: @Fargho Are you going to search partial or full text search?

Answer (score 2):

A bunch of hints:

- It's a bit excessive to put searching through 60,000 items on the front-end. Any way you can perform part of the search on the back-end? If you really *must* do it on the front-end considering searching in chunks of e.g. 10,000  and then using a `setImmediate()` to perform the next part of the search so the user's browser won't completely freeze during processing time.
- Do the splitting and lowercasing of the search term outside of the loop.
- `map()` like you're using it is weird as you don't use the return value. Better to use `forEach()`. Better still, is use `filter()` to get the items that match.
- When iterating over the search terms, use `some()` (as pointed out in the comments) as it's an opportunity to early return.
- `sort()` mutates the original array so you don't need to re-assign it.
- `sort()` with `reverse()` is usually a smell. Instead, swap the sides of your condition to be `b - a`.
- At this scale, it may make sense to do performance tests with `includes()`, `indexOf()`, roll-your-own-`for`-loop, `match()` (can almost guarantee it will be slower though)

Comment: Also, doing `map()` or even `forEach()` over the split search terms is weird; you don't want to keep searching once you've decided that you will add `item` to `searchResults`.  Probably [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's suggestions are good. My only suggestion would be, if you could afford to pre-process the data during idle time (preferably don't hold up first render or interaction) you could process the data into a modified prefix trie. That would let you search for the items in O(k) time where k is the length of the search term (right now you are searching in O(kn) time because you look at every item and then do an `includes` which takes k time (it's actually a little worse because of the `toLowerCase`'s but I don't want to get into the weeds of it).

If you aren't familiar with what a trie is, hopefully the code below gives you the idea or you can search for information with your search engine of choice. It's basically a mapping of characters in a string in nested hash maps.

Here's some sample code of how you might construct the trie:

```js
function makeTries(data){
    let companyTrie = {};
    let titleTrie = {};
    data.forEach(item => {
        addToTrie(companyTrie, item.company, item, 0);
        addToTrie(titleTrie, item.title, item, 0);
    });
    return {
        companyTrie,
        titleTrie
    }
}

function addToTrie(trie, str, item, i){
    trie.data = trie.data || [];
    trie.data.push(item);

    if(i >= str.length)
        return;
    if(! trie[str[i]]){
        trie[str[i]] = {};
    }
    
    addToTrie(trie[str[i]], str, item, ++i);
}

function searchTrie(trie, term){
    if(trie == undefined)
        return [];
    if(term == "")
        return trie.data;
    return searchTrie(trie[term[0]], term.substring(1));
}

var testData = [
    {
        company: "abc",
        title: "def",
        rank: 5
    },{
        company: "abd",
        title: "deg",
        rank: 5
    },{
        company: "afg",
        title: "efg",
        rank: 5
    },{
        company: "afgh",
        title: "efh",
        rank: 5
    },
];

const tries = makeTries(testData);
console.log(searchTrie(tries.companyTrie, "afg"));
```